Plugin architecture with __init_subclass__ and ABC
I recently wanted to implement the plugin architecture in Python and found that there are multiple approaches to achieve this. I stumbled upon various answers, but one way that I am not understanding is the use of __init_subclass__  with the ABC module.
Taking as an example quasoft's example, the only point of using ABC instead of a Singleton object for the Plugin class would be to force the use of abstract methods?
Therefore, would be the following example correct or am I missing a better approach with ABC? Is it really that simple?
class Interface(ABC):
    
    subclasses = []

    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls.subclasses.append(cls)
    
        
    @abstractmethod
    def start_work(self) -> None:
        pass


class Concrete1(Interface)
   
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        id = "Concrete1"

    def start_work(self):
        print(f"{self.id} is doing some work!")
   
class Concrete2(Interface)
   
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        id = "Concrete2"

    def start_work(self):
        print(f"{self.id} is doing some work!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for plugin in Interface.subclasses:
        plugin.start_work()

